# java get i'th element from permuted value

Tags: java, permutation

```
 static void possible_combination(int[] a, int k) {
    if (k == a.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" [" + a[i] + "] ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        for (int i = k; i < a.length; i++) {
            int temp = a[k];
            a[k] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
            possible_combination(a, k + 1);
            temp = a[k];
            a[k] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Function call is:`possible_combination(array, 0);` 
If I give input array contains elements like 1 2 3, I got output like

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

in this output, I have to get element like n'th row value. For Example, if I give 3, I need 3'rd row value 2 1 3 .

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Access the kth location of a?  Are you trying to find all possible orders of the values in a and then find the kth ordering?  There are a.length! combinations of orderings of the values of a, not a.length orderings, in case you're checking for that in your if statement

Comment: if given input array has 3 elements means(1, 2, 3), i got 6 output .but the a.length is 3. i could not understand how does it works. for example,from the out put elements i need to get 1,3,2. i mean this 1,3,2 is 2'nd row value.how to get?

Comment: What are the rows of [1, 2, 3] as the input?  Please list them

Comment: the input array contains [1 2 3] means, the output is [2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 3] from this output i need [3,1,2] element only. how to get?

Comment: In this case it seems like you'd want to replace almost every instance of `a.length` with it's factorial instead.  Your for loop is a bit confusing as to what it's doing with k, since k should be able to go up to 5 or 6 in your example

Comment: @RC. That's for an array, if they output the different combinations to an array then it would work

Comment: if i need [1,3,2] means, it is something[4]. but a.length is always 3. how to? can u suggest any other code for permutation?

Comment: @RC,@phflack. I found solution. public String getPermutation(int n, int k) {  n = arr2length; if (n <= 0 && k <= 0) { return ""; } int fact = 1;    
 List<Integer> intList1= new ArrayList<Integer>();  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { fact *= i; intList1.add(i); } StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();        for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {    fact /= i; int rank = (k - 1) / fact; k = (k - 1) % fact + 1; sb.append(intList1.get(rank));intList1.remove(rank); }  return sb.toString(); }

Comment: now my problem is to find smallest number from the StringBuilder output. help?

Comment: now my problem is to find smallest number from the kth sequence of permuted sequences. i could not achieve it. bz the output of kth element comes as BuilderString format. pls suggest code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try like this

```
import java.util.*;
class Array13
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int arr[][]={{1,2,3},
    {1,3,2},
        {2,1,3},
        {2,3,1},
    {3,1,2},
        {3,2,1}};
System.out.println("Enter the row number :");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int r = sc.nextInt();


printVal(arr,r-1);

}
public static void printVal(int mat[][],int row)
{
for(int i=0;i<mat.length;i++)
{
if(i == row)
{
for(int j=0;j<mat[row].length;j++)
{
System.out.print(mat[i][j]);
System.out.print(" ");
}
}
}
}

}
```